# How to create unique method for url parameters?

Tags: python, json, django, url, parameters

This is my get method:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        myObject = myObjectClass.objects.all()
        serializer = myObjectSerializer(myObject, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Let's assume that response looks in this way:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data1": 12,
    "data2": "example1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data1": 11,
    "data2": "example3"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "data1": 12,
    "data2": "example3"
  }
]
```

I would like to create method using URL http://localhost:8000/data/?data1=12 to get in response:

```
 [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "data1": 12,
        "data2": "example1"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "data1": 12,
        "data2": "example3"
      }
 ]
```

My problem is that I would like to create unique method. For instance we could use URL [http://localhost:8000/data/?data2="example3"](http://localhost:8000/data/?data2=%22example3%22) and in response we would get:

```
 [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "data1": 11,
            "data2": "example3"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "data1": 12,
            "data2": "example3"
          }
     ]
```

I wonder if this is possible? What is the best solution? I have been trying with request.GET, request.GET.get() etc., but nothing works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`request.GET.get()` should work for the retrieving the query parameter you are sending.Something along the lines of:

```
if request.GET.get('data1'):
    print request.GET.get('data1')

if request.GET.get('data2'):
    print request.GET.get('data2')
```

Alternatively you can use dynamic url patterns using regex.

Comment: But I have to do every case separately. Maybe there is one method that fits all cases?

Comment: You mean have separate views for each case? If yes, then your answer is dynamic url patterns like `xyz.com/data1/` with get data as `{data1: "example"}` and `xyz.com/data2/` with get query as `{data2: "some more"}`.